# How do I whiten an old deer skull?

Tags: deer, bones

Yesterday I found a really old deer skull in a forest and I took it home in the hope to get it cleaned up. So I searched it up but I only saw how to clean up dead deer heads with skin on and those who are already white almost. But I could not do the same because the one I found was old....Really old...It did not have any skin whatsoever and its antlers where gone.

It misses half its teeth. And it's super green...So can I use hydrogen peroxide like usual or something else to whiten it up or at least something that takes away the germs? Or should I throw it back into the forest?

Comment: Just Google for "whitening bones for display".

Comment: @RoryAlsop No its on topic, it might be a dupe https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7114/how-to-clean-bones-found-outside/7115#7115  https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20862/skull-soaking-in-hydrogen-peroxide-for-days-still-brown https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/24442/whats-the-best-way-to-preserve-a-skull-without-bleaching but its not off topic

Comment: Hanna this question would be on topic at [Lifehacks SE](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Apologies -looks like I was too hasty on the closing.  Thanks Charlie

Answer (score 2):

Hydrogen peroxide or a light bleach solution will work. Another good way is leaving it outside in direct sunlight for a month or two.